# react redux useSelector() always returns a promise

Tags: react-native, react-redux, local-storage, asyncstorage

I am using react redux to add cart functionality to my app.  I store data in local storage using

```
store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()));


const saveToLocalStorage = async (state: any) => {
    try {
        const serialisedState = JSON.stringify(state);
        await Storage.setItem("cartState", serialisedState);
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
    }
}
```

load data from local using

```
const store = createStore(cartItems, loadFromLocalStorage());

const loadFromLocalStorage = async () => {
    try {
        let data = await Storage.getItem('cartState');
        data = data != null ? data : JSON.stringify(initialState)
        return JSON.parse(data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error Storging data', error);

    }
}
```

when I try to get data using useSelector() hook I always get a promise and cannot get data from there

```
const state = useSelector( state  => { return state });
```

how can I get data from promise or return actual data from loadFromLocalStorage() function?

Comment: The docs says that you need to use `@` symbol when u use the `getItem` method.
https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api#getitem

Comment: Thanks but this is not related to my question...by the way if I log something on the console inside this function loadFromLocalStorage() I get everything as expected

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue using this

I created  index.tsx file in reducers folder and here is the code

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import cartItems  from "./cartItems";

const rootReducers = combineReducers({ cartItems: cartItems });

export default rootReducers;
```

and using that rootReducers in createStore() method like this

```
const store = createStore(rootReducers, loadFromLocalStorage());
```

also not sure why but I had to change this arrow funtion loadFromLocalStorage to this in order to get it working

```
function loadFromLocalStorage() {
    try {
      const serialisedState = AsyncStorage.getItem("cartState");
      if (serialisedState === null) return undefined;
      return JSON.parse(serialisedState);
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
      return undefined;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check in store, if have this async: delete it